# Convert division equation (String) into a Double

Tags: java, scriptengine

I am trying to convert a division equation (String) into a double, and then be able to add or subtract from it. Eclipse gives me a "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int" error.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class EVCalc {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String ShutterSpeed = "1/50";
    Double.parseDouble(engine.eval(ShutterSpeed).toString());

    System.out.println(engine.eval(ShutterSpeed)+1);
  } 
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add it to the question. Eclipse keeps giving me a "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int"

Comment: assign the value returned from `parseDouble` to a `double` variable and use in the last line.

Comment: Unrelated, but still a good tip: Convention says not to start variable names with a capital letter unless they are constants.

Comment: I get a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Double" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the return value from `Double.parseDouble()`:

```
double parsedValue = Double.parseDouble(engine.eval(ShutterSpeed).toString());

System.out.println(parsedValue + 1);
```